# while-loop: list index out of range filtering dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, indexing, while-loop

Essentially I have a list full of numerical identifiers -- I use these numerical identifiers as a condition to filter down a dataframe, then once the df is filtered down, I am attempting to store the length of the filtered down dataframe as values in a new, separate dataframe.

I am using the last value in my list of numerical identifiers (ex. `list[-1]`) as the stopping point for my loop -- I did this so the loop would run thru all the identifiers and finish after its gone through the last one -- I assume this is potentially where the issue is.

My code is spitting out all the correct lengths as it goes through all the unique numerical identifiers in the list -- however, it is still giving me an index out of range error (shown below).

```
def get_frames(U_id):
    k = sorted(df.trackId.unique())
    #k is the sorted list of unique numerical identifiers
   i = 0
   maximum = k[-1]  #am using the final value in the list as the stopping point for the loop

    while i <= maximum:
        condition = df.trackId == k[i]
        df2 = df[condition]
        values = print(len(df2))
        df2 = pd.DataFrame({U_id:values}, index = [i])
        i+=1
return df2

get_frames('1CCM0701')
```

```
 36
 18
 37
 4
 33
 25
 27
 49
 46
 12
 45
 24
 4
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-120-3252dfb603ae> in <module>
13     return df2
14
 ---> 15 get_frames('1CCM0701')

 <ipython-input-120-3252dfb603ae> in get_frames(U_id)
 6     maximum = k[-1]
 7     while i <= maximum:
  ----> 8         condition = df.trackId == k[i]
 9         df2 = df[condition]
10         values = print(len(df2))

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you are using k[-1] as the stopping point when you are using an iterating variable that accesses the array through an index. k[-1] is **36**, which is obviously unrelated to the length of your array. Instead, you should a for loop, or have i be compared to the length of the array instead.

Pythonic For loop:

```py
for i, val in enumerate(k):
    condition = df.trackId == val
    df2 = df[condition]
    values = print(len(df2))
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({U_id:values}, index = [i])
```

Traditional For Loop

```py
for i in range(len(k))
    condition = df.trackId == k[i]
    df2 = df[condition]
    values = print(len(df2))
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({U_id:values}, index = [i])
```

While Loop

```py
arrLen = len(k)
while i < arrLen:
    condition = df.trackId == k[i]
    df2 = df[condition]
    values = print(len(df2))
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({U_id:values}, index = [i])
    i+=1
```

Comment: Shouldn't the condition of the `while` loop be `i < arrLen`? Otherwise, when `i` equals `arrLen`, you'll get a `IndexError: list index out of range` again.

Comment: @yeeshue99 awesome that works perfectly. really appreciate the help